# Inflate Exception when Switching Between Orientations and Having Dynamic Non UI Fragments and Separate Layout Files

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been looking at this and trying to figure the problem out for a day now, but with no luck. I usually ask questions as a final measure, so I am kind of desperate right now as nothing that was recommended in other questions worked for me... And I've been trying hundreds of solutions. It could be that I am just having problems figuring out the correct way of asking it.

Here is what I have in my project:

**A base fragment activity class that all activities in my project extend:**

```
public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements IActivity {

    protected CacheFragment cacheFragment;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity#onOptionsItemSelected(com.
     * actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        NavigationHandler.switchToActivity(this, item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(this.isHomeButtonEnabled());
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(this.isHomeDisplayedAsUp());
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the home button is enabled.
     * 
     * @return <code>TRUE</code> if the home button is enabled.
     */
    public abstract boolean isHomeButtonEnabled();

    /**
     * Returns whether the home button should be displayed as an up button with
     * a arrow on the left.
     * 
     * @return <code>TRUE</code> if the home button should be shown with an
     *         arrow.
     */
    public abstract boolean isHomeDisplayedAsUp();

    /**
     * Gets the cache manager of the given fragment activity.
     */
    public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
        if (this.cacheFragment == null) {
            this.cacheFragment = CacheFragment.getOrCreateCacheFragment(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        }
        return this.cacheFragment.getCacheManager();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity#onPause()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (this.cacheFragment != null) {
            this.cacheFragment.getCacheManager().flushDiskCache();
        }
    }
}
```

**A home activity with two different layouts for portrait (in layout-port) and landscape, which extends the base activity class:**

Portrait:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/teaserFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha.fragments.TeaserListFragment" >
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Landscape:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/teaserFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha.fragments.TeaserListFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/articleFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/article_detail_landscape_margin_left"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        class="com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha.fragments.ArticleFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Teaser fragment:**

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >

</ListView>
```

**Article fragment**:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollArticle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutLinear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**A cache fragment:**

```
public class CacheFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CacheFragment";

    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    public CacheFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Gets the application cache fragment or creates a new one.
     */
    public static CacheFragment getOrCreateCacheFragment(final FragmentManager fm, final Context context) {
        CacheFragment result = (CacheFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(CacheFragment.TAG);
        if (result == null) {
            result = new CacheFragment();
            result.cacheManager = new CacheManager(context);

            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(result, CacheFragment.TAG);
            ft.commit();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
        return this.cacheManager;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
     * android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

The idea of the cache fragment is to have no UI and to be used and retained during configuration changes. All disk accesses are done on a thread different than the main one.

Here are two scenarios now:

1. Start the application in landscape mode - everything is fine, things are visualized normally and there are no problems at all when I change the orientation or do whatever with the app.
2. Start the application in portrait mode - the problems come here... When I switch the orientation I am expecting to get the master-detail layout. The activity gets recreated and should use the landscape layout, the **CacheFragment** should be there, since it was created to retain its instance and this seems to be the case. I see the call to the **onCreateView** of the first layout fragment (**TeaserListFragment**) and then I get the following exception:

LogCat:

```
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha/com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:840)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:27)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 12 more
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.nikolov.ivan.android.metalafisha.fragments.ArticleFragment did not create a view.
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:293)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
09-08 15:41:37.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 21 more
```

Seems like something strange is going on when I have the **CacheFragment** created before switching to landscape mode.

Another thing I notice is that I see calls to the **onCreateView**, when the Android documentation states that it should not be called for no UI fragments.

I made sure that I have IDs in the layout file, I even checked if they are globally unique for the application and many other things that seemed reasonable, but I still see the same result. The only way this doesn't happen is if I don't add the **CacheFragment** with the transaction, but then there is really no point of having it...

Based on the message it looks like Android is confusing the **CacheFragment** with the **ArticleFragment**...

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I seem to run out of ideas what I can be doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... After a few days of banging my head and trying to make sure that it's not my code that is wrong, I looked for the solution in the Android code and I found it in a few minutes. The lesson is that from now on, I should actually look in the Android issue tracker first...

I found directions to my answer here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22564&q=fragment%20did%20not%20create%20a%20view&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

As you can see from my example, I have two layouts for the different orientations. What happens is that when the activity is created for portrait, only one UI fragment is added and another one, which is headless. Headless fragments are added to a **viewId == 0**. This is a really important point for understanding what is going on.

Now have a look at the support-v4/r7 code, and more specifically **lines 225 to lines 303** of the FragmentActivity class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (!"fragment".equals(name)) {
        return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    }

    String fname = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "class");
    TypedArray a =  context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, FragmentTag.Fragment);
    if (fname == null) {
        fname = a.getString(FragmentTag.Fragment_name);
    }
    int id = a.getResourceId(FragmentTag.Fragment_id, View.NO_ID);
    String tag = a.getString(FragmentTag.Fragment_tag);
    a.recycle();

    View parent = null; // NOTE: no way to get parent pre-Honeycomb.
    int containerId = parent != null ? parent.getId() : 0;
    if (containerId == View.NO_ID && id == View.NO_ID && tag == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(attrs.getPositionDescription()
                + ": Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for " + fname);
    }

    // If we restored from a previous state, we may already have
    // instantiated this fragment from the state and should use
    // that instance instead of making a new one.
    Fragment fragment = id != View.NO_ID ? mFragments.findFragmentById(id) : null;
    if (fragment == null && tag != null) {
        fragment = mFragments.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
    if (fragment == null && containerId != View.NO_ID) {
        fragment = mFragments.findFragmentById(containerId);
    }

    if (FragmentManagerImpl.DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onCreateView: id=0x"
            + Integer.toHexString(id) + " fname=" + fname
            + " existing=" + fragment);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, fname);
        fragment.mFromLayout = true;
        fragment.mFragmentId = id != 0 ? id : containerId;
        fragment.mContainerId = containerId;
        fragment.mTag = tag;
        fragment.mInLayout = true;
        fragment.mFragmentManager = mFragments;
        fragment.onInflate(this, attrs, fragment.mSavedFragmentState);
        mFragments.addFragment(fragment, true);

    } else if (fragment.mInLayout) {
        // A fragment already exists and it is not one we restored from
        // previous state.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(attrs.getPositionDescription()
                + ": Duplicate id 0x" + Integer.toHexString(id)
                + ", tag " + tag + ", or parent id 0x" + Integer.toHexString(containerId)
                + " with another fragment for " + fname);
    } else {
        // This fragment was retained from a previous instance; get it
        // going now.
        fragment.mInLayout = true;
        // If this fragment is newly instantiated (either right now, or
        // from last saved state), then give it the attributes to
        // initialize itself.
        if (!fragment.mRetaining) {
            fragment.onInflate(this, attrs, fragment.mSavedFragmentState);
        }
        mFragments.moveToState(fragment);
    }

    if (fragment.mView == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + fname
                + " did not create a view.");
    }
    if (id != 0) {
        fragment.mView.setId(id);
    }
    if (fragment.mView.getTag() == null) {
        fragment.mView.setTag(tag);
    }
    return fragment.mView;
}
```

This is the **onCreateView** method. Now take a deeper look at the following line:

```
int containerId = parent != null ? parent.getId() : 0;
```

Let's imagine that we started the app in portrait mode. This means that we have two fragments in our activity: the TeaserListFragment with its ID and the headless fragment. If we now switch the orientation, we will have to add another fragment - the ArticleFragment, which is the second one in the landscape layout file. Here is what will happen:

1. The TeaserListFragment will be found by the ID, because it was already created.
2. Since the ArticleFragment was not created we will get to the shown line above and a few lines later, based on the logic, we will have the following call:

Line 255:

```
fragment = mFragments.findFragmentById(containerId);
```

This will return the headless fragment (because of the viewId mentioned above) instead of **null** and this is why the error will occur. I managed to debug it and change the value of the containerId to -1 and it worked fine. In general, the solution would be to comment out the following code:

```
if (fragment == null && containerId != View.NO_ID) {
    fragment = mFragments.findFragmentById(containerId);
}
```

These are lines 254 to 256. Also having the default value for the containerId being -1 should be fine, but I believe removing the redundant **if** is better in order to preserve the check for not set IDs...